# Whitebox is not finding my java

Tags: java, whitebox-gat

I was recently presented to the software Whitebox GAT 'Iguazu'. Unfortunately, I tried to use it in two different machines: one with Windows 7 (64) + JRE 7 (65) and other with W7 (64) + JRE 7 (67) . In both computers I could not start the program.

I tried double click and also open specifying the program path. Nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Whitebox GAT 3.2.0, the program has required the installation of the latest Java runtime environment, the JRE 8.0. This is because I have started to take advantages of some of the newer features offered in the latest version of the Java programming language. As a result, updating to Whitebox 3.2.0 requires an update of your JRE. After you've installed the JRE 8.0, you should find that Whitebox can be launched simply by double-clicking the Whitebox JAR file contained within the program's directory.

Comment: Thks. It worked!